Failed assertion when validating sorting order
I need help in understanding why does the test fails when sorting by descending/ascending order, and what possible options to fix it?
Here is the failure text :
Expected sortedColumnEntries to be in descending order, but found {"17_2", "14_8", "14_5", "13_2", "10_8", "8_5", "5_13", "5_6", "3_7", "3_3", "3_3", "2_5, ..."} where item at index 0 is in wrong order.

Code(DDT test):
var sortedColumnEntries =
    customPage.GetValuesForColumn(columnName);
if (customPage.Grid.Header[columnName].IsSortButtonAscending) {
    using (new AssertionScope()) {
        customPage.Grid.Header[columnName].IsAscending.Should().BeTrue();
        sortedColumnEntries.Should().BeInAscendingOrder(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
} else {
    using (new AssertionScope()) {
        customPage.Grid.Header[columnName].IsSortButtonDescending.Should().BeTrue();
        customPage.Grid.Header[columnName].IsAscending.Should().BeFalse();
        sortedColumnEntries.Should().BeInDescendingOrder(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}

public IEnumerable <string> GetValuesForColumn(string columnName) {
    if (columnName == "Title") {
      return GetTitlesOnCurrentGrid();
    }

    var headers = Grid.Header.HeaderItems.ToList();
    var columnHeader = headers.First(x => x.Text == columnName);
    var columnIndex = headers.IndexOf(columnHeader);
    return Grid.RowItems.Select(i => {
      if (columnName == "Tutor" && i.MultipleTeacherRowItem.Visible) {
        i.MultipleTeacherRowItem.HoverMouse(isLongHover: true);
        return i.MultipleTeacherRowItem.TooltipText;
      }

      return i[columnIndex].Text;
    });


"Title" is a different column therefore the method skips the if statement.
It is worth to be noticed, that the values can also exist under the column as below:
"-_1"
"--"

I've tried several options of StringComparer class (such as Ordinal, etc) but nothing helps.

Could it be that the test fails because sortedColumnEntries is not what you think it is?

I don't think so, this is UI test and before it gets the entries into GetValuesForColumn it clicks on the column to sort the entries by order (descending/ascending).

What exactly are you trying to fix? Either the test for ascending/descending order doesn't work, or your sortedColumnEntries really is out of order. There aren't any other options here. The data you presented, in particular the error message, indicates that sortedColumnEntries is out of order. Tell us why you think that it isn't.

I'm not sure why the error message is saying the item at index 0 is out of order, but clearly the one at 5 is. The string "8_5" is definitely greater than the string "10_8" as strings are sorted character by character. If you're intending to sort them numerically, I don't know what the "_" character is supposed to represent, can you tell us why 5_13 is supposed to be greater than 5_8? Is it actually two separate numbers?

JimMischel:
That was the reason I asked it in here as I do not understand it myself. As for me, it works as it should. When we sort by descending order, so this should be the sequence: "17_2", "14_8", "14_5"
@iakobski
The column contains string values "Module_Submodule - 5_13". So the '_' just divides modules and submodules. 5_13 should be greater in the list as it contains submodule which is greater than its counterpart - 5_8.
However, I think I am getting to understand the failure reason as you said it compares char by char.

If you want them to be sorted like the file name in Windows File Explore, either of the options in the StringComparer enumeration won't do what you need. you'll need to use Win32_Api StrCmpLogicalW. It will

Compares two Unicode strings. Digits in the strings are considered as numerical content rather than text. This test is not case-sensitive.

Then, you could use StrCmpLogicalW to implement a IComparer<string>, like this:
public class LogicComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);

    public int Compare(string? x, string? y)
    {
        if(x == null && y == null)
            return 0;
        if(x == null)
            return -1;
        if(y == null)
            return 1;
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }
}

And then, it will be OK:
var entries = new List<string>() { "17_9", "14_8", "14_5", "13_2", "10_8", "8_5", "5_13", "5_6", "3_7", "3_3", "3_3", "2_5"};
entries.Should().BeInDescendingOrder(new LogicComparer());

As for why the failure message indicates that index is 0, because the logic of method BeInDescendingOrder, is that:
step1: get the correct descending order:
{"8_5", "5_13", "5_6", "3_7", "3_3", "3_3", "2_5", "17_9", "14_8", "14_5", "13_2", "10_8"}

step2: Compare each element.
So, it will find that the first element is incorrent.
